# Maintain display configuration regardless of display connection status

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, amd-graphics, xrandr

I'm really not sure the best phrasing for this question, so I apologize for anything confusing.

I have a computer running Kubuntu 18.04 with a single AMD GPU (`amdgpu-pro` driver) with four outputs connected. When all four displays are connected and running, I have them mapped as a single display (using the videowall KWin script, though I've used Xinerama and `xrandr --setmonitor` in the past as well). That works great, but if something changed (e.g. a display is disconnected or turned off), the configuration is lost and the Xinerama-style mapping breaks, causing my fullscreen application to revert from fullscreen across all displays to fullscreen across a single display.

To try to get around this, I created a startup script, placed in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` that runs a few `xrandr` commands.

```
xrandr --addmode DisplayPort-0 1920x1080
xrandr --addmode DisplayPort-1 1920x1080
xrandr --addmode DisplayPort-2 1920x1080
xrandr --addmode HDMI-A-0 1920x1080
xrandr --output DisplayPort-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate left --output DisplayPort-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1080x0 --rotate left --output DisplayPort-2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 2160x0 --rotate left --output HDMI-A-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 3240x0 --rotate left
```

This solves the issue when a display isn't detected on boot, forcing it to be configured anyways. Remote access shows that the displays are configured as I want. However, if I reconnect a display, or power one off or on, it has the same problem as above. It seems there is some sort of hotplug event that causes xrandr to reconfigure itself, and undoes the configuration I set up as well as the kwin script.

I'm trying to find a way around this so that either:

1. The computer either thinks these four displays are always connected
2. Kubuntu simply ignores the hot plug event
3. I have a watchdog script that watches for the hotplug event (or monitors the configuration comparing it to the expected configuration) that can restore the configuration to what it should be.
4. Any other solution you can think of. Those were just what I could come up with as potential fixes.

On a Windows machine with an NVidia card I accomplished step one by manually setting the EDIDs in the NVidia control panel. I haven't been able to replicate that in Kubuntu with NVidia or AMD.

Any help is appreciated!